# Running utop with dune conflict: extlib and base64

Tags: ocaml, utop, ocaml-dune

I have a project which uses `extlib` and `base64`. `dune` is used in the build process. The build works fine, but when I try to run `dune utop`, I get the following message:

```
[<me>@<me> js2sil]$ dune utop
File "<home>/.opam/ocaml-variants.4.07.1+flambda/lib/base64/base64.cma(Base64)", line 1:
Warning 31: files <home>/.opam/ocaml-variants.4.07.1+flambda/lib/base64/base64.cma(Base64) and <home>/.opam/ocaml-variants.4.07.1+flambda/lib/extlib/extLib.cma(Base64) both define a module named Base64
```

This seems to be a known issue. On the `extlib` page, it lists `base64 < 2.0.0` as a conflict, which implies that later versions should not conflict (I have version `3.2.0`). Is there something I'm missing? Is it just not feasible to build a custom toplevel with both of these packages? Thanks for any help!